# How could i combine two (or more) tables into a temporary table?

Tags: mysql, sql

There's a code, in which i could join all 5 tables together and it works fine. But i want to to make a temporary table from it so it could be easier for me to work next with this lines, and with `create temporary table` it doesn't work. So could you show me how to do it properly?

```
select * from city
    join shipment sh on city.city_id=sh.city_id
    join customer cus on sh.cust_id=cus.cust_id
    join driver dr on sh.driver_id=dr.driver_id
    join truck tr on  sh.truck_id=tr.truck_id
```

The error is

> Duplicate column name 'city_id'

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? Please post details of the statement that doesn't work as well as whatever evidence you have (error message, perhaps?) that it doesn't work. If it does something, but not what you intended, then please post details of your intended outcome.

Comment: Why not create a view instead?

Comment: Please show what you have tried and what error message did you receive in response. Also, please describe your tables. You can easily do so via running `select TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, COLUMN_TYPE from information_schema.tables where TABLE_NAME in ('shipment', 'customer', 'driver', 'truck') order by TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME;`

Comment: I tries as in example below and it gives me an error [Code: 1060, SQL State: 42S21] Duplicate column name 'city_id'.

Comment: Means what it says - using * (selecting all columns from all tables)  here is just wrong you should specify the columns you need fully qualified by table name to avoid duplicate column names which you obviously have in city and shipment.. cust_id,driver_id and truck_id are also clear duplicates

Comment: And you may need alias names if you take  columns with the same name from different tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create a temporary table, you must have the `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES` privilege. - Read about it here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-temporary-table.html

When you have that, you can do something like this:

```sql
CREATE temporary TABLE name_of_temp_table
  SELECT *
  FROM   city
         JOIN shipment sh
           ON city.city_id = sh.city_id
         JOIN customer cus
           ON sh.cust_id = cus.cust_id
         JOIN driver dr
           ON sh.driver_id = dr.driver_id
         JOIN truck tr
           ON sh.truck_id = tr.truck_id
```

However, there is also an option to create a view such as:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-view.html

```sql
CREATE VIEW name_of_view
AS
  SELECT *
  FROM   city
         JOIN shipment sh
           ON city.city_id = sh.city_id
         JOIN customer cus
           ON sh.cust_id = cus.cust_id
         JOIN driver dr
           ON sh.driver_id = dr.driver_id
         JOIN truck tr
           ON sh.truck_id = tr.truck_id
```

Comment: Yes, i tried it and it gives me the next error: [Code: 1060, SQL State: 42S21]  Duplicate column name 'city_id'. I guess it's because there are same columns in different tables.
Same applies and to the View.

Comment: Then you don't have a problem with creating a temporary table, but with the query itself. I would believe that your `city` table doesn't have `city_id`, but just `id`, which would make more sense, and then in your joins, you shouldn't be doing `city.city_id = sh.city_id` but `city.id = sh.city_id`. 

Please check if your query works as expected and do you have columns in tables properly set.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have columns of the same name in several tables. To avoid this from causing troubles, you will need to list your columns, like

```
select TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, COLUMN_TYPE 
from information_schema.columns 
where TABLE_NAME in ('city', 'shipment', 'customer', 'driver', 'truck') 
order by COLUMN_NAME, TABLE_NAME;
```

You will need to find out which of them are duplicated.

Actually you can generate your query parts like this:

```
select CONCAT('insert into yourtable(', GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME), ') values ' GROUP_CONCAT('(''', existing.TABLE_NAME, '''.''', existing.COLUMN_NAME, ''')'))
from information_schema.columns existing
left join information_schema.columns notexisting
on existing.TABLE_NAME in ('city', 'shipment', 'customer', 'driver', 'truck') and
   notexisting.TABLE_NAME in ('city', 'shipment', 'customer', 'driver', 'truck') and
   CONCAT('''', existing.TABLE_NAME, '''.''', existing.COLUMN_NAME, '''') < CONCAT('''', notexisting.TABLE_NAME, '''.''', notexisting.COLUMN_NAME, '''')
where nonexisting.TABLE_NAME is null
```

(untested)

Anyway, you will need to avoid duplicating the columns names in your temporary table's definition.